# Getting an ArrayIndexOutOfboundsException when splitting a string into an array and then looping over it

Tags: java

I am trying to send the result of a `split()` function into an array of strings, but I am getting an exception as follows:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: somenumber

I am using the following code, but it returns that exception:

```
String[] temp;
temp = result.split(" ");
```

Any suggestions? I want to send the result of the string `split()` function into an array of strings, and then print the values in a for loop.

I am getting an out of bounds exception in for loop, I use:

```
for (int i=0;i<=temp.length;i++)
{
    out.println(temp[i]);
}
```

Comment: What does this relate to javascript?

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't even compile, as you can't assign a string array to a `String` variable. Please post a short but complete program which *does* compile.

Comment: @King Aslan, see my edited answer: it should explain fairly well on why the new error is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String temp;
String[] split = result.split(" ");
temp = split[temp.length - 1];
```

You were declaring a String array as a single string, then declaring a new String in the wrong way.

EDIT: saw you updated your post:

You have to use less then for the condition in the for loop. If an array has 5 elements, the last element will be 4, not 5. The correct code is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
  System.out.println(temp[i]);
}
```

You can even do:

```
for(String cur : temp){
  System.out.println(cur);
}
```

Comment: No problem. If you want, feel free to do some challenges on CodingBat. They are good for these type of methods and will help explain. I am currently making a similar program but offline.

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` method ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)) returns an Array of String, so your `temp` variable should be a `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work like that. `split` returns `String[]`.

```
String someString = "hello world";
String[] split = someString.split(" ");
String hello = split[0];
String world = split[1];
String lastWord = split[split.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
String[] parts = original.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the result (length of the array?) in the same array that generated the split() function, then you can't. You would have to create another array of bigger length:

```
String result = "Hello World";
String[] temp;
temp = result.split(" ");
String[] temp2 = Arrays.copyOf(temp, temp.length + 1);
temp2[temp.length] = String.valueOf(temp.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp2));
```

The output is: [Hello, World, 2]